# Installing icalendar (or other Python modules) in Google App Engine project

Tags: python, google-app-engine, icalendar

I'm trying to install the icalendar Python module for use in my Google App Engine project. I have created a Python virtual environment in my project folder, and installed the icalendar package in it. If I run the Python interpreter from the venv, I can import icalendar and use it just fine (help(icalendar) shows it's getting the module from the correct path: venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/icalendar). I have created a symlink called icalendar pointing to that directory in my project root (same place as app.yaml). The project can deploy and run on GAE, but anytime it tries to use icalendar, I get "Cannot import module 'icalendar'".

I used the exact same steps to install the [Twilio library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/python) in my app, which worked fine. If I don't include the symlink to the Twilio module, the error message is actually 'No module named twilio', instead of "Cannot import..". Not sure if that's relevant.

I've seen this: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-appengine/FM_NXd9cbus, which is exactly my problem, but there was no solution!

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I also tried just putting the icalendar module directory in the project root, w/o the symlink. No difference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check [how to use python libraries in GAE](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27).

Pay attention as the docs are a bit confusing, you need to pick one (and only one) solution for a library, you can't mix both (they're both chapters on the above-mentioned page):

- [Requesting a library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#requesting_a_library) - for libs supplied by GAE - for these check notes for what you may need to do for your local development server
- [Installing a library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#installing_a_library) - for additional libraries you need to include in your app - for these check also the restrictions the library needs to meet